# Trouble with Java File I/O?

Tags: java, file, methods, io

I'm having some trouble with I/O. I have a class called SongTextFileProcessor that's supposed to handle the reading/writing of a Song object (defined in a Song class) to/from a file. Here's my write method:

```
@Override
public void writeSong(String songName, String fileName) 
{
    String [] songObject = songName.split(", ");
    Song s1 = new Song (songObject[0], songObject[1], songObject[2]);

    try
    {
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter (new File (fileName));
    output.print(s1.printSong());
    output.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception caught.");
    }
}
```

And my read method:

```
@Override
public void readSong(String fileName) 
{
    try
    {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

    String line = null;
    while((line = in.readLine()) != null)   
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    in.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception caught.");
    }
}
```

However, when I try to invoke these methods from a Test class using this code:

```
String songName = "Maad City, Kendrick Lamar, Hip-Hop";
String fileName = "songs.txt";

writeSong(songName, fileName);
readSong(fileName);
```

it gives me the error "the method writeSong(String, String) is undefined for the type Test". This frustrates me because I'm familiar with Java I/O, and with Java in general, and when both of these methods are invoked from the Test class they work perfectly, which means the problem must be in the process of passing the arguments to the method in SongTextFileProcessor. Any ideas?

Here's the song class:

```
public class Song 
{
private String title, artist, genre;

public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) 
{
    this.title = title;
}

public String getArtist() 
{
    return artist;
}

public void setArtist(String artist) 
{
    this.artist = artist;
}

public String getGenre() 
{
    return genre;
}

public void setGenre(String genre) 
{
    this.genre = genre;
}

public Song(String title, String artist, String genre)
{
    this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.genre = genre;
}

public String printSong()
{
    return (getTitle() + " by " + getArtist() + " is a " + getGenre() + " song.");
}
}

The readSong and writeSong methods are the only methods in the SongTextFileProcessor class, and both of those methods are defined by Interfaces. And i've shown all the code I have in the Test class.
```

Comment: provide yr song class

Comment: U need to show the whole code so that your question becomes more clear.

Comment: In which class your `writeSong()` located and from where your calling it?can you provide those classes?

Comment: writeSong() and readSong() are both in a separate class called SongTextFileProcessor that's supposed to deal with writing/reading Song objects to/from a text file.

Comment: in which class `main` method is located?

Comment: main is in the Test class

Comment: You are calling `writeSong()` without any reference.Since both the methods are non-static methods,u need to call them using reference to an object of  `SongTextFileProcessor` class.

Comment: Yes, i called them using SongTextFileProcess.writeSong(), and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: you should call close() in a finally block. Either explicit or implicit in a try-with-resource construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in text class:

```
    String songName = "Maad City, Kendrick Lamar, Hip-Hop";
    String fileName = "songs.txt";

    SongTextFileProcessor stfp = new SongTextFileProcessor ();

    stfp.writeSong(songName, fileName);
    stfp.readSong(fileName);
```